# There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Instance of 'Partner'

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

My dropdown working as expected . but when I selected a item my app crashing with error

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Instance of 'Partner'. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
```

First I declare my variable in class

```
    class _MultipleTestBookingState extends State<MultipleTestBooking> {

 Partner? _selectedLab;
 Datum? _selectedTest;
 ....................
```

declare with `Partner?_selectedLab;` because my dropdown menu takes in a list of Partners

Then using this variable to show the selected value in my dropdown

```
 Container(
                  child: FutureBuilder<List<Partner>>(
                    future: AllPathLab(),
                    builder:
                        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState !=ConnectionState.done) {
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text("Somthing went wrong");
                      }

                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return DropdownButton<Partner>(
                           value: _selectedLab,
                          hint: Text("Select Lab"),
                    items: snapshot.data.map((Partner data) =>
                    DropdownMenuItem<Partner>(
                                              child: Text("${data.partnerName}"),
                                              value: data,
                                            )
                                            ).toList().cast<DropdownMenuItem<Partner>>(),
                      onChanged: (value){
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedLab=value;
                          encLabId = value!.encPartnerId;
                          GetTestByLab(); 
                        }); 

                      }
                      
                      );
                          
                        }
                      return Text("Waiting for Internet Connection");
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

[Full code with my JSON response](http://gist.github.com/Roy-Tuhin/85dae5e908b21c92cb19a7f3c82dc0e7)

Comment: Please check if you are fetching the data in proper manner. if Possible you can add the AllPathLab() and the sample json format that the api is fetching.

Comment: I believe I'm fetching my data correctly because clicking dropdown its showing up all my data from API. Giving the error when I change my `_selectedLab` in setState .

Comment: I put  the link for  My API fucntion and my  JSON response . Can you please check it now  [ https://gist.github.com/Roy-Tuhin/85dae5e908b21c92cb19a7f3c82dc0e7 ]

Comment: yes i am checking it, as you have two api hits you have provided only one json sample please provide both and let me know

Comment: ohh! The second api for my dependent dropdown list.. I added the json response file  called `Get Test by Lab response`  [ https://gist.github.com/Roy-Tuhin/85dae5e908b21c92cb19a7f3c82dc0e7 ]

Comment: Ok i did saw it some people don't want to fetch via api. ok checking now

Comment: People taking the global variable like- `String  _selectedLab=""`  but my dropdown menu takes in a list of `Partners` so I have to declare my variable `Partner? _selectedLab` (causing problem) ?

Comment: Check the answer below that i have mentioned and its a working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from the data that you provided i have created the code below:

```
import 'package:date_time_picker/date_time_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/Patner.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/dataModel.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Partner _selectedLab;
  Datum _selectedTest;
  Future getAllPathLabResults;
  Future getTestByLabResult;

  String encLabId = '';

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllPathLabResults = allPathLab();
    getTestByLabResult = getTestByLab();
  }

  String _selectedDate = DateTime.now().toString();

  Future<List<Partner>> allPathLab() async {
    String jsonData = jsonstring;
    final model = modelFromJson(jsonData);
    print("This is the list length : ${model.partner.length}");

    List<Partner> arrData = model.partner;
    // this Future is for sample as you will be fetching the api data remove this one
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    return arrData;
  }

  Future<List<Datum>> getTestByLab() async {
    print("This is the Id :$encLabId");
    _selectedTest = null;
    var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse("http://medbo.digitalicon.in/api/medboapi/GetTestByLab"),
        body: ({"EncId": encLabId}));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final dataModel = dataModelFromJson(response.body);
      print(dataModel.data.length);
      for (final item in dataModel.data) {
        print("This is hte test name :${item.testName}");
      }

      List<Datum> arrData = dataModel.data;
      return arrData;
    }

    return [];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var blockSizeHorizontal = (screenWidth / 100);
    var blockSizeVertical = (screenHeight / 100);

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text("Booking Information",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: blockSizeHorizontal * 5,
                        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      )),
                  subtitle: Text("Preferred Visit Date"),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 150),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.lightBlue[50],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: DateTimePicker(
                    initialValue: DateTime.now().toString(),
                    //initialValue:'', // initialValue or controller.text can be null, empty or a DateTime string otherwise it will throw an error.
                    type: DateTimePickerType.date,
                    dateLabelText: 'Select Date',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: blockSizeHorizontal * 3.5,
                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                      color: Colors.green,
                      letterSpacing: 2.0,
                    ),
                    firstDate: DateTime.now(),
                    lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 30)),
                    // This will add one year from current date
                    validator: (value) {
                      return null;
                    },
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedDate = value;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                        _selectedDate = value;
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  "Select Pathological Lab",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: blockSizeHorizontal * 4.0,
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              Container(
                child: FutureBuilder<List<Partner>>(
                  future: getAllPathLabResults,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("Somthing went wrong");
                    }

                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      List<Partner> data =
                          snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data : [];
                      return DropdownButton<Partner>(
                        value: _selectedLab,
                        hint: Text("Select Lab"),
                        //underline: SizedBox(),
                        //isExpanded: true,
                        items: data
                            .map((Partner data) => DropdownMenuItem<Partner>(
                                  child: Text("${data.partnerName}"),
                                  value: data,
                                ))
                            .toList()
                            .cast<DropdownMenuItem<Partner>>(),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _selectedLab = value;

                            encLabId = value.encPartnerId;
                            getTestByLabResult = getTestByLab();
                          });
                          //GetTestByLab(value!.encPartnerId); // passing encid to my next API function
                          // GetTestByLab();
                        },
                      );
                    }
                    return Text("Waiting for Internet Connection");
                  },
                ),
              ),

              //=========================================================== Dependent drop down===================================

              ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  "Test Name",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: blockSizeHorizontal * 4.0,
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              Container(
                child: FutureBuilder<List<Datum>>(
                  future: getTestByLabResult,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("Select a Lab for your Test");
                    }

                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      List<Datum> data = snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data : [];

                      return DropdownButton<Datum>(
                          value: _selectedTest,
                          hint: Text(""),
                          //underline: SizedBox(),
                          //isExpanded: true,
                          items: data
                              .map((Datum data) => DropdownMenuItem<Datum>(
                                    child: Text("${data.testName}"),
                                    value: data,
                                  ))
                              .toList()
                              .cast<DropdownMenuItem<Datum>>(),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            print("This is the value : ${value.testName}");
                            setState(() {
                              _selectedTest = value;
                            });
                            //GetTestByLab(value!.encPartnerId); // passing encid to my next API function
                          });
                    }
                    return Text("Waiting for Internet Connection");
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// used this as a sample 
String jsonstring = '''{
  "Status": "1",
  "Message": "",
  "Partner": [
    {
      "EncPartnerId": "IujyQXg8KZg8asLvK/FS7g==",
      "PartnerName": "dasfdsf"
    },
    {
      "EncPartnerId": "pEl2B9kuumKRxIxLJO76eQ==",
      "PartnerName": "partner172"
    },
    {
      "EncPartnerId": "eYwtNBXR6P/JDtsIwr+Bvw==",
      "PartnerName": "nnkb"
    },
    {
      "EncPartnerId": "kFgorcFF0G6RQD4W+LwWnQ==",
      "PartnerName": "nnkjj"
    },
    {
      "EncPartnerId": "U4exk+vfMGrn7cjNUa/PBw==",
      "PartnerName": "mahadev"
    },
    {
      "EncPartnerId": "tqkaSjTFgDf0612mp9mbsQ==",
      "PartnerName": null
    },
    {
      "EncPartnerId": "0aruO0FbYOu5IerRBxdT8w==",
      "PartnerName": "Suraksha Diagnostics"
    },
    {
      "EncPartnerId": "65gtodyhbtdInTsJWr1ZkA==",
      "PartnerName": "Rasomoy pvt. Hospital"
    },
    {
      "EncPartnerId": "LEuT1eIlpLEMAAkZme3wpQ==",
      "PartnerName": "Tangra medical House"
    },
    {
      "EncPartnerId": "q8O8YMzYKXSB4RtkX4k7Lw==",
      "PartnerName": "Partner new"
    }
  ]
}''';
```

Models for the apis:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final model = modelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Model modelFromJson(String str) => Model.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String modelToJson(Model data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Model {
  Model({
    this.status,
    this.message,
    this.partner,
  });

  String status;
  String message;
  List<Partner> partner;

  factory Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Model(
        status: json["Status"],
        message: json["Message"],
        partner:
            List<Partner>.from(json["Partner"].map((x) => Partner.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Status": status,
        "Message": message,
        "Partner": List<dynamic>.from(partner.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Partner {
  Partner({
    this.encPartnerId,
    this.partnerName,
  });

  String encPartnerId;
  String partnerName;

  factory Partner.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Partner(
        encPartnerId: json["EncPartnerId"],
        partnerName: json["PartnerName"] == null ? null : json["PartnerName"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "EncPartnerId": encPartnerId,
        "PartnerName": partnerName == null ? null : partnerName,
      };
}
```

second api parsing model

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final dataModel = dataModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

DataModel dataModelFromJson(String str) => DataModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String dataModelToJson(DataModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class DataModel {
  DataModel({
    this.status,
    this.message,
    this.data,
  });

  String status;
  String message;
  List<Datum> data;

  factory DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DataModel(
        status: json["Status"],
        message: json["Message"],
        data: json["Data"] == null
            ? []
            : List<Datum>.from(json["Data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Status": status,
        "Message": message,
        "Data":
            data == null ? [] : List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Datum {
  Datum({
    this.testId,
    this.encTestId,
    this.testName,
    this.noOfPartner,
    this.testFee,
    this.discountedFee,
    this.bookingFee,
    this.reportTime,
    this.note,
    this.createBy,
    this.createDate,
    this.modBy,
    this.modDate,
    this.activeStatus,
    this.permission,
  });

  String testId;
  dynamic encTestId;
  String testName;
  dynamic noOfPartner;
  dynamic testFee;
  dynamic discountedFee;
  dynamic bookingFee;
  dynamic reportTime;
  dynamic note;
  dynamic createBy;
  dynamic createDate;
  dynamic modBy;
  dynamic modDate;
  dynamic activeStatus;
  dynamic permission;

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        testId: json["TestId"],
        encTestId: json["EncTestId"],
        testName: json["TestName"],
        noOfPartner: json["NoOfPartner"],
        testFee: json["TestFee"],
        discountedFee: json["DiscountedFee"],
        bookingFee: json["BookingFee"],
        reportTime: json["ReportTime"],
        note: json["Note"],
        createBy: json["CreateBy"],
        createDate: json["CreateDate"],
        modBy: json["ModBy"],
        modDate: json["ModDate"],
        activeStatus: json["ActiveStatus"],
        permission: json["Permission"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "TestId": testId,
        "EncTestId": encTestId,
        "TestName": testName,
        "NoOfPartner": noOfPartner,
        "TestFee": testFee,
        "DiscountedFee": discountedFee,
        "BookingFee": bookingFee,
        "ReportTime": reportTime,
        "Note": note,
        "CreateBy": createBy,
        "CreateDate": createDate,
        "ModBy": modBy,
        "ModDate": modDate,
        "ActiveStatus": activeStatus,
        "Permission": permission,
      };
}
```

So when you initially fetch the data based on the id and select the second dropdown. now when you change the lab you have the make the selected text to null.
and you are are also using the futurebuilder method in wrong manner as there is setstate getting called it is creating multiple rebuids and giving error.

please run the code and check if its working.

Comment: ok, trying! Quick question: Can I get my `Lab` data from Api? `Future<List<Partner>> allPathLab() async { String jsonData = jsonstring;` As we getting data for `Test` by api calling

Comment: currently the above code is for  fetching the json that you provided from string, use your code from the gist that you provided, it will not change.

Comment: make an api call check for 200 success and then from response.body you get the data  add it in this one final model = modelFromJson(response.body);